# How to add <script> to Angular2

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I add

```
<script>
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
        transPeriod: 500,
        time: 3000,
        height: '490px',
        thumbnails: false,
        pagination: true,
        playPause: false,
        loader: false,
        navigation: false,
        hover: false
    });
});
```

to my angular page ? Is there any nice solution to do something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your script into a new file, like `myScript.js`.

Then, in your `index.html` add:

```
<script src="/path/to/myScript.js"></script>
```

Save file and refresh page. Now you have your script running into Angular app.